# How can I autocomplete Forms in Django with Foreign Keys?

Tags: python, django

My intention is that the form takes the available book with its respective foreign key but I cannot with the `book_id` field of loans.

I have managed to take the user crazy but not the book

```
# Model
class Prestamos (models.Model):
    libro_id = models.ForeignKey(Libros, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usuario_id = models.ForeignKey(Usuarios, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantidad_dias = models.SmallIntegerField('Cantidad de dias a prestar', default= 5)
    fecha_prestamo = models.DateField('Fecha de prestamo', auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    fecha_vencimiento = models.DateField('Fecha de vencimiento de la reserva', auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null = True, blank = True)
    estado = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name= 'Prestado')
```

```
# Form
class PrestamoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in iter (self.fields):
            self.fields['cantidad_dias'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = False
    class Meta:
         model = Prestamos
         fields = [ 'cantidad_dias']
         exclude = ['libro_id', 'usuario_id','fecha_prestamo','fecha_vencimiento', 'estado']

    def clean_libro(self):
        libro = self.cleaned_data['libro_id']
        if libro.cantidad < 1:
            raise ValidationError('No se puede prestar este libro, no hay unidades disponibles')
        return libro
```

```
# View
class RegistrarPrestamo(CreateView):
     model = Prestamos
     template_name = 'libro/prestar_libro.html'
     success_url = reverse_lazy('libros:disp_libro')
     form_class = PrestamoForm

     def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.usuario_id = self.request.user
        libro= Libros.objects.get(pk=int(id))
        form.instance.libro_id = libro
        return super (RegistrarPrestamo, self).form_valid(form)
```

```
#Url
path('libro/prestar-libro/', login_required(RegistrarPrestamo.as_view()), name = 'prestar_libro')
```

[image: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method']

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from the fact that you're passing he builtin [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=id#id) function to `int()`

Where you're querying for your `libro` object you need to pass a number;

`libro = Libros.objects.get(pk=1)`

You also don't need to include `clean_libro` in your form because you've excluded the `libro` field from it (and not added a field by that name).

If you're looking to assign a `Libro` object to your new `Prestamos` instance which isn't already linked to another object, you could query for the libra objects already in the table and then get the next available object for your new `Prestamos` instance. That'd be something like;

```py
     def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        libro_ids = Prestamos.objects.values_list('libro_id', flat=True)
        unassigned_libro = Libros.objects.exclude(id__in=libra_ids).first()
        instance.usuario = self.request.user
        instance.libro = unassigned_libra
        return super (RegistrarPrestamo, self).form_valid(form)
```